# Why does my Crystal Report print in portrait when using the report viewer?

Tags: crystal-reports

I've got a report that I created in Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010.

The report is set to landscape. If I create an instance of the report, load it with data and print it using the following code, it prints in landscape as expected.

```
        var rpt = new MyReport();
        rpt.SetDataSource(dataSource);
        rpt.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 1, int.MaxValue);
```

If I view the report in the Crystal Report viewer control for WPF using the following code, the report is shown correctly in landscape mode.

```
        var rpt = new MyReport();
        rpt.SetDataSource(dataSource);
        ReportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = rpt;
```

However, if I click the Print button in the Crrystal Report Viewer control, the print comes out as portrait, truncating the right side of the report and not filling the page top to bottom.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is a fix for this but it seems like a few people are having the same problem. I found a couple of links that might help.

On [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vscrystalreports/thread/16ecedb6-8888-4385-8b78-bfe235afd33a) (about half way down) a guy suggests setting your default printer Microsoft XPS Document Writer. Not sure why that would work but worth a try.

This second [link](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-168179.html) seems more promising. They mention that the Report Viewer is very buggy and that by using the ReportDocument instead you can override the PaperOrientation property of the report and set it to Landscape manually.

Let me know if these links help.

Comment: I'm actually testing against the XPS Writer so that doesn't help unfortunately. The problem with the other method shown is that it's printing directly. I actually use that method elsewhere in the software for reports that don't need to be viewed first. On this one the customer wants to view the report to check it before printing. Hence the use of the viewer. TBH, I get the impression that the whole of CR is a little shoddy at the moment, including the installer for the software! The customer uses CR though so I have no other option.

Comment: Richard - What do they want to do in the viewer? Is it just a print preview? As a possible workaround could you raise a PDF instead?

Comment: At the moment it's a print preview but with an element of interactivity. I don't think a PDF would be acceptable.

Comment: 5 years on, is anyone close to an answer for this?

Comment: @MikeDWakelyn Not yet. The only way is to avoid using the print button and implement your own button with a call to `PrintToPrinter`.